# launching a jquery pop up window on html form submit?

Tags: php, jquery, html, submit

can anyone please help. i have this login form:

```
<form id="myform" form action="login.php" method="post" class="loginform">
Email
<input type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" />
Password
<input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" />
<input type="image" src="../PTB1/assets/img/icons/loginarrow1.png" name="submit" class="loginbutton" value="Login" />
</form>
```

i also have this script which brings up the form action page "login.php" in a popup window when my form is submitted.

at the moment it brings up a basic pop up window but i want to know if i can tweak the jquery code to implement a jquery lightbox window which opens up instead.

heres the jquery code that launches the pop up window when my login form is submitted.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=400,height=400');
        this.target = 'formpopup';
    });
});
</script>
```

but now i want to have this pop up window open using my jquery lightbox window which is called "shadowbox" (available to download on the net) which you would normally open your links with like so.

```
 <a href="link"   rel="shadowbox;height=300;width=500"        >link</a>
```

so just to be clear, i am asking if there is a way to launch my jquery lightbox "shadowbox" in place of the normal pop up window which is being launched when the user clicks the submit button on the login form.

Please can someone show me a way of doing this. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add e.preventDefault() to the previous statement

```
$(function() {
  $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.target = 'formpopup';
    Shadowbox.open({
      content:    'link',
      height:     300,
      width:      500
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $('#myform').submit(function() {
    this.target = 'formpopup';
    Shadowbox.open({
      content:    'link',
      height:     300,
      width:      500
    });
  });
});
```